# how to get rid of decimal points in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Hi I have a weird requirement

if an amount value is 0.00 i need to display it as 0 
and if its something else like
23.12 I need to have the decimal points and display as 23.12...
tried below code in netezza but doesn't work

```
select 
case when amount=0.00 then 0
else amount
end;

select case when amount=0.00 then to_char(amount,99)
else to_char(amount,999999.99)
end;
```

they work when I write as select to_char(amount,99) from _v_dual;
but doesn't work in case statement I get error like invalid format in to-char...

am completely stuck here any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in my Netezza db

```
select to_char(0.00,99) from _v_dual;
select 
case when amount=0.00 then 0
else amount
end
from
(select 0.00 as amount) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting single quotes around your format strings?

`select to_char(amount,'99')`